# Word for a lucky object?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for a lucky object, a thing you hold in your hand for good luck?  Perhaps a stone.  A small object that represents good fortune. I think it begins with *tal-*

Like a necklaces of a Hawaiian God (like in that Partridge Family TV episode.)  You might even rub it or keep it in your pocket when you go to Vegas.

Comment: A talisman. Next! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking of a [talisman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talisman)

> A talisman is an object which is believed to contain certain magical
>   or sacramental properties which would provide good luck for the
>   possessor or possibly offer protection from evil or harm

Answer (score 1):

Amulet; Fetish; and then there's Charm or Rabbit's foot ... finding as in jewelry.